# Mincom always connected to /dev/ttyS0

Tags: usb, serial-port, minicom

I have set my minicom serial port with the following default conditions:

```
pu port             /dev/ttyUSB0
pu mdialpre         
pu mdialsuf         
pu mdialpre2        
pu mdialsuf2        
pu mdialpre3        
pu mdialsuf3        
pu mconnect         
pu rtscts           No
```

But when I start minicom I always get conected to /dev/ttyS0 as shown below:

```
Welcome to minicom 2.7

OPTIONS: I18n 
Compiled on Nov 15 2018, 20:18:47.
Port /dev/ttyS0, 05:23:44

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys
```

I would like to connect to `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Please assist me in rectify the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest try starting minicom by specifying the device using:

```
minicom-D /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Then once it is started use CTRL-a z (control a then z) to got into the minincom menu and configure the defaults from there.